# How do you make Webpack compile JS code with Liquid tags in it?

Tags: webpack, shopify, liquid

Im working a few components to work on Shopify stores and I really hate to have code spread all over the templates. Im using Webpack to build my project, problem is Webpack build breaks when it finds any Liquid tag such as `{{ product }}`. Is there any way Webpack can be configured for this to work?

Comment: You would need to process those files through a loader to turn the code into valid JavaScript. If you need to retain the tags, then you would need a post-process (webpack plugin most likely) to restore them (JavaScript -> liquid). I'm missing some context so I cannot give an exact answer.

Comment: The files need to retain Liquid syntax `` {{ somevar }} `` so im guessing your second hypothesis is what I need. Tried looking into handlebars loaders, which have a similar syntax, but those work differently by processing the file. Here I just need it to ignore those strings somehow.

Comment: It's probably quite unlikely you'll find something that does exactly what you want. It's that reverse part (js back to liquid) that feels tricky. But look around. Maybe there is something similar to adapt.

Comment: Thank you bebraw. I was afraid that would be the case. Will look further and update this if I find any solution.